# Does the letter k in electromagnetics represent wavenumber inside a cosine?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic

I am having a intellectual debate with a colleague on whether k (in this equation below) represents the wavenumber k (that is used in electromagnetics) or does k in this question not refer to wavenumber k and is k just some letter? My understanding of this question is that t is time, z is space, and k is wavenumber.

The question states:
The magnetic field of a wave in free space and in cylindrical coordinates is given by
[image]
where t is in seconds, and r and z are in meters.
(a) Determine k.
(b) Assume k = 1 (rad/m). Consider a square contour C in the y = 0 plane as shown in the following figure. Find the line integral of the electric field along C in the direction shown
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does. The unit for wavenumber k is radians/m (2*pi/lambda) and unit for z(coordinate) is meters. When you multiply both, you end up with radians inside a cosine. Which is perfectly logical.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand. You are saying that it's clear from the question that k is implied to be the wavenumber? Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @user5574422 it is kind of always like that, https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ba/af/cf/baafcfbd84a36db775cb1c0dfd8abdfc.jpg

Comment: I’ve also seen wavenumber’s nomenclature also be the Greek letter “nu” which is \$\nu\$, kind of looks like a Latin “v”.

Comment: @KingDuken I have seen "nu" as frequency during most of my learning, so it automatically represents frequency to me. But don't know if it is common among the entire community or not.

Comment: @muyustan In my experience, frequency is usually *f* if given in Hz, or *ω* if in rad/s.

Comment: @Hearth yes, of course, *f* is the dominant one for Hz. I think I was seeing "nu" for frequency in replace of  *f* mostly on physics classes, so it can be something not used in electronics area.

Comment: @Hearth ok, at least wikipedia experienced it as I did. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Planck%E2%80%93Einstein_relation

Comment: Apologies, I was just simply stating that I've also seen "nu" as [linear wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber) (see under "Definition"), I wasn't trying to say/imply that you were wrong with your answer. I think I got my definitions mixed up with _linear_ wavenumber and _angular_ wavenumber.

Comment: @KingDuken I end up learning what a *linear wavenumber* is, thanks.